# PUT, POST, and DELETE Routes in Laravel 5.1 returns 400 bad request

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

I've read different blogs and forums regarding my problem but have no luck. The problem is that when i tried my routes (Post, Delete, Put) with postman the result is always 400 (Bad Request) but my Get routes are all perfectly working. I already tried to comment VerifyCsrfToken in my kernel.php but still not working. Here is my route list.

[image]

In my routes.php,

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'publications'], function()
{
    Route::get('/{id}', [
        'uses' => 'PublicationController@show'
    ]);

    Route::post('/', [
        'uses' => 'PublicationController@store'
    ]);

    Route::put('/{id}', [
        'uses' => 'PublicationController@update'
    ]);

    Route::delete('/{id}', [
        'uses' => 'PublicationController@destroy'
    ]);
});
```

And in my controller,

```
public function show($id)
{
    return 'sdasdsadas';
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    return '1';
}

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    return '2';
}

public function destroy($id)
{
    return '3';
}
```

Controller `return` are just a test whether the routes are entering the controller. And in my postman i'm accesing the route with `http://localhost:8000/api/v1/publications/1` using delete and it returns 400 bad request. If you encounter this with laravel please share your experiences and how did you solve it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean "using delete" ?

Comment: I'm using the postman method 'delete' to test my api, but i don't know why the output is always 400 bad request `The request cannot be fulfilled due to bad systax`.  Same as `Put` and `Post` methods.

Comment: Maybe the postman method is not including the hidden input `_method` with value `DELETE` that Laravel needs to know it is a DELETE method?

Comment: @Amarnasan I think the hidden field is an alternative for the actual request method. So if the request is done using a DELETE request method, it's fine too.

Comment: @Amarnasan I tried adding `_method` with a value of `DELETE` and its still not working.

Comment: Besides including the `_method` input, you need to set the actual method of the post to  `POST`.  Did you?

Comment: @Luceos But in this page  http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html they say "Since `HTML` forms only support `POST` and `GET`, `PUT` and `DELETE` methods will be spoofed by automatically adding a `_method` hidden field to your form".

Comment: @Amarnasan yeah same results. Why do I need to include `_method`? Does postman add the method delete when you use it? I'm trying to use `restangular` for my angularjs app but I got the error so i tested it with postman and I got the same error with restangular.

Comment: Thank you sir. I finally solved it. it's because of the `\Neomerx\CorsIlluminate\CorsMiddleware::class`.

Answer (score 0):

For those who encountered this, try to use https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors in your laravel routes. This solves my problem regarding CORS when using Restangular with Laravel Rest Api.